# Calculation on Dynamic Rows using jAutoCalc Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-calculation

Am trying to do multiple simple calculations using the [jAutoCalc.js jquery plugin](https://github.com/c17r/jAutoCalc) in a form where the rows are dynamically added/removed. Please visit this link to see the live demo. While the calculation works for the first row it is not happening for the subsequent rows. Also I like to sum all the total values using the same plugin and stick it in the 'Sum of Total' input box at the bottom.Thanks in advance for helping me out.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Write JavaScript here 
function addRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if (rowCount < 4) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    //var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-1);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    row.id = 'row_'+rowCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;            
    }
   var listitems= row.getElementsByTagName("input")
        for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
          listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
        }
} else {
    alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");

}
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 1) { // limit the user from removing all the fields
            alert("Cannot Remove all the Records.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}
}
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/c17r/jAutoCalc/master/jAutoCalc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[name=cart] tr[name=line_items]').jAutoCalc({keyEventsFire:  true, decimalPlaces: 2});
    $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc({decimalPlaces: 2});

});
//-->
</script>
<body>
<form name="cart">
<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr name="line_items" id='row_0'>
        <p>
            <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>

            <td>
                <label>Qty</label>
                <input type="text" size="1" required="required" class="qty" name="qty" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="cuprice">Price</label>
                <input type="text" size="3" required="required" class="price" name="price" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="ctp">Total</label>
                 <!--<td><input type="text" size="3" readonly class="total" name="total" id="total" /></td>-->
                 <td><input type="text" name="item_total" value=""  jAutoCalc="{qty} * {price}"></td>

            </td>

        </p>
    </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
</form>
 Sum of Total:<input type="text" name="sum"/>
  </body>
```

Plugin Link: https://github.com/c17r/jAutoCalc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now using 'Calx' jQuery Plugin to do the calculation on a form where the rows are created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin author here.  I've updated the sample at http://c17r.github.io/jAutoCalc/sample to include dynamically adding/removing rows.

The whole thing runs off field-level events in a tree structure; it gets off the rails a bit when things are changed.  The simplest approach is to wrap your code to wire up jAutoCalc into it's own function

```
function autoCalcSetup() {
    $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc('destroy');
    $('form[name=cart] tr[name=line_items]').jAutoCalc({keyEventsFire: true, decimalPlaces: 2, emptyAsZero: true});
    $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc({decimalPlaces: 2});
}
```

And call that function whenever you add/remove a row.  The first line will remove any previous wire up if it exists.